# How can I import gspread 5.4.0 into a Colab Notebook

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, version, gspread

When I import gspread into a Colab notebook it imports version 3.4.2. I want to work with gspread Version 5.4.0 in Colab. Is there a way to do that? Tx.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in a cell

```
!pip install gspread==5.4.0
```

Then you will need to restart the runtime

After that, the following shows the version

```
import gspread
gspread.__version__

# '5.4.0'
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine. it was the == I was missing. I notice my code I was using for the earlier version to authenticat loading of my google drive no longer works. So I guess my next question is how to authentic and mount my drive if I'm using 5.4.0?